# How do you add a class to an appended element that is created when contenteditable adds new paragraph tag when pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I'm using Hashedit (contenteditable) and when I press enter on an editable body of text (paragraph element), it appends a new paragraph element. However, I want the new paragraph element to also have the same class as the one I pressed enter on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function init() {
  $("#my-div").on("keydown",function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
      //Do your thing when enter is pressed
      setTimeout('$("p:last").addClass("cool-class")',10);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.cool-class {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="init()">
  <div contentEditable id="my-div">
    <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
    <p>Bla bla</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Uses jQuery.